# Converting text content to bitmap (MonoDroid)

Tags: android, text, bitmap

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I wonder if anyone has (or has seen) a class/componet which would work in Monodroid for the conversion of something textual (plain text, html, xml, anything really) into bitmap format.

I have seen (and have used) numerous examples, which turn text into a bitmap, but as yet, each on has been to create a bitmap > canvas > text object > add text > wash > rinse > repeat, which makes from some VERY messy and cumbersome code when you have quite a lot of text to output.

I did look at the HTMLRenderer classes, but cannot quite seem to get them to work (or find a working version) due to the use of the System.Drawing.Graphics, which isn't yet implemented in Monodroid (such a shame, as HTML to Image would have been perfect)

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, the recent version of HTML Renderer (v1.5) provides cross framework support, the core library depends only on 'System' and there is an extensibility model for framework specific rendering, maybe you can create MonoDroid rendering like the currently existing WinForms/WPF/PdfSharp.

See [this blog post](http://theartofdev.com/2014/10/09/html-renderer-1-5-0-0/), hope it helps.